# Sails.js Waterline query by association

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm developing and app with Sails.js and using Waterline orm for db. I'm developing functionality for users to do friend requests and other similar requests to each other. I have following URequest model for that:

```
    module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        owner: {
            model: 'Person'
        },

        people: {
            collection: 'Person'
        },

        answers: {
            collection: 'URequestAnswer'
        },

        action: {
            type: 'json'    //TODO: Consider alternative more schema consistent approach.
        }
    }
};
```

Basically owner is association to Person who made the request and people is one-to-many association to all Persons who the request is directed. So far fine.

Now I want to have a controller which returns all requests where certain user is involved in meaning all requests where user is either in owner field or in people. How I do query like "give me all rows where there is association to person P" ? In other words how I ca know which URequest models have association to a certain Person?

I tried something like this:

```
getRequests: function (req, res) {
    var personId = req.param('personId');
    URequest.find().where({
    or: [
        {people: [personId]},   //TODO: This is not correct
        {owner: personId}
        ]
}).populateAll().then(function(results) {
        res.json(results);
    });

},
```

So I know how to do the "or" part but how do I check if the personId is in people? I know I should somehow be able to look into join-table but I have no idea how and couldn't find much from Waterline docs relating to my situation. Also, I'm trying to keep this db-agnostic, though atm I'm using MongoDB but might use Postgres later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to be honest this is a tricky one, and, as far as I know what you are trying to do is not possible using Waterline so your options are to write a native query using query( ) if you are using a sql based adapter or native otherwise, or try doing some manual filtering.  Manual filtering would depend on how large of a dataset you are dealing with.

My mind immediately goes to reworking your data model a bit, maybe instead of a collection you have a table that stores associations.  Something like this:

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    owner: {
        model: 'URequest'
    },

    person: {
        model: 'Person'
    }
}
```

Using the sailsjs model methods (like beforeCreate) you could auto create these associations as needed.

Good Luck, I hope you get it working!

Comment: This is almost how I ended up doing it in the end. I created a manual join table with model having associations to request and person which I can then find with doing queries to this new join table. What I didn't realize was using beforeCreate methods for join-table creation So thanks!